# ggplot2: how to create scatterplot of a variable against itself, under different conditions?

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I'm looking at some gene expression data. I pooled together data from 12 different CSV files, and the final data format is as follows:

```
lib gene_id     expression
1   a           0
1   a_reverse   10
1   b           15
1   b_reverse   0.3
2   a           10
2   a_reverse   0
2   b           0.3
2   b_reverse   15
3   a           8
3   a_reverse   15
3   b           0.3
3   b_reverse   0.5
...
```

You get the idea. There are 12 libraries for `lib`, each of them containing the expression levels for 5000 genes and 5000 reverse genes.

Now, I want to create a scatterplot of these expression values against each other. If these were in different variables, then to plot the genes of lib 2 vs lib 1, I'd simply do something like:

```
plot(library1$expression, library2$expression)
```

However, because `expression` is technically the same variable in my data frame, I'm not sure how to proceed. I can't afford to simply load every CSV as a separate variable, because I'm looking to export my data as 1 large CSV file after processing. To make my plot in `ggplot2`, I imagine it'd look something like this:

```
ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(df[lib==1]$expression, df[lib==2]$expression))
```

However, I know this is way off, because when I try it gives me an error. What's the correct syntax to do this right? Also, if at all possible I'd also like to be able to create a pairs plot for all the genes of each library against every other library (kind of like ggpairs). How do I go about doing this?

Comment: You should `reshape2::cast` or `tidyr::spread` your data into wide format (turn the `lib` values into columns with `expression` as its values, maybe drop the `gene_id` entirely)  and then `GGally::ggpairs` will make all your plots at once.

Comment: Is there a way to tidyr::spread on JUST the expression column, while keeping the gene_id column un-spreaded? I'd like to keep the gene_id as a key for identifying points of interest from my scatterplot.

Comment: Sure, as long as your `gene_id`'s are the same for every `lib` value it will work fine. `tidyr::spread(library, key = lib, value = expression)`. You might want to rename the resulting columns, pasting `"lib"` in front of the numeric column names. (Or maybe `library$lib = paste0("lib", library$lib)` before spreading.)